# Unexpected alert open chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get text from an alert which has been opened and closed respectively.

I am using ChromeDriver for automation.

Here is my code :

```
System.out.println("Requesting to be Share as Only");
WebElement lnkShare = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkRequest']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", lnkShare);
lnkShare.click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkShare']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkShare']")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_Dashboard_ucProgressbar_imgLoader']")));
driver.switchTo().frame("fbContent");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdoRequestShareOnly']")).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
String alertText = alert.getText();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
System.out.println("getting in if loop");

if (alertText.contains("Net Size/Gross Size")) {
    System.out.println("Present");
} else {
    System.out.println("not");
}

System.out.println("out of loop");But I get the following error :
```

> org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open:
>   {Alert text : Error detected when attemption to Share! The following
>   fields are missing: Net Size/Gross Size Vendor Please confirm and try
>   again.}

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out , problem was there is another iframe in which a element was located .